# Designing sequence diagrams and design patterens

Tags: design-patterns, uml, software-design

1) Can someone tell me how is the grasp pattern related to sequence diagram?
2) If I am given a problem like to draw the sequence diagram and indicate grasp pattern how can I do it? Say for example the software system has the requirements like searching,selecting,  retreiving, updating and saving the student info the student database, i would draw the sequence diagram for it but how do indicate the grasp pattern for the same.

Answer (score 2):

GRASP is an acronym, coined by Craig Larman, that names several previously well-known principles to consider as you design software, such as "ensure high functional cohesion". A UML sequence diagram depicts an example of how a design works, as operation calls among classifiers. You don't explicitly model GRASP principles on a sequence diagram, as you might with a GoF pattern such as "observer". Instead, you remember to apply these principles as you design.